# I have both Signed Apk and Bundle but the size of Signed apk is smalled then signed bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, bundle

I have both Signed Apk and Bundle but the size of Signed apk is smalled then signed bundle. Same is the case the download size of both. I need a little help that what i have to publish on google play.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the GooglePlaystore you have to publish your .aab file. (You can find more information here https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle). You find your File here after you created it:
username/AndroidStudioProjects/Appname/app/release